# having my authentication in a different controller in grails?

Tags: grails, controller

So I have a successful log in with my grails application. 
But I want to separate out some functions into different controllers.

example:

```
package MyApp

class CustomerController {

/*Keeping the scaffold for admin purposes.*/   
static scaffold = Customer

//write redirects and make exceptions for scaffolds
//  def index() { }  

/*
 * Access controllers are ordered after application flow. 
 **/

def login(){    
}

/*
 * Authentication based on email adress as the identifier.
 * 
 **/
def authenticate() {
    def authPwd 
    def authUser

    if(User.findByEmail(params.email) == null){

      flash.message = "login failed"
      redirect(action: "login")

    }else{
        authUser = User.findByEmail(params.email)
        authPwd = authUser.getPassword()        

        if(authPwd == params.pwd){
            session["user"] = authUser
            session["customer"] = authUser.getCompany()

            println "current user is: " + session["user"]
            println "current customer is: " + session["customer"]

            redirect(controller: "portal", action: "start")
        }else{
            flash.message = "login failed"
            redirect(action: "login")
        }
    }
}

def logout() {
    session.invalidate()
    redirect(action: "login")
}

}
```

So what i want to do is take the authenticate() out of here and put it in a new controller called AuthenticateController()

only,being new to grails, my redirect is not working and i was hoping someone could give me an idea why.

So what i thought you would take out the

```
def authenticate {
/* some code*/
}
```

put it in the new controller. then just use

```
redirect(controller: "authenticate", action: "authenticate")
```

but this does not work and i get an error exception.

Any help would be much appreciated

Edit: for the purpose of the comment below...

```
class CustomerController {

/*Keeping the scaffold for admin purposes.*/   
static scaffold = Customer

//write redirects and make exceptions for scaffolds
//  def index() { }  

/*
 * Access controllers are ordered after application flow. 
 **/

def login(){  
    redirect(controller:"authenticate", action:"authenticate")
}

/*
 * Authentication based on email adress as the identifier.
 * 
 **/


def logout() {
    session.invalidate()
    redirect(action: "login")
}

}
```

Then the AuthenticateController

```
class AuthenticateController {

def authenticate() {
    def authPwd 
    def authUser

    if(User.findByEmail(params.email) == null){

      flash.message = "login failed"
      redirect(contoller:"customer", action: "login")

    }else{
        authUser = User.findByEmail(params.email)
        authPwd = authUser.getPassword()        

        if(authPwd == params.pwd){
            session["user"] = authUser
            session["customer"] = authUser.getCompany()

            println "current user is: " + session["user"]
            println "current customer is: " + session["customer"]

            redirect(controller: "portal", action: "start")
        }else{
            flash.message = "login failed"
            redirect(contoller:"customer", action: "login")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Is the code that does not work. Basically a copy and paste.

Tomcat runs but with 100's of errors first

```
type Status report

message /ClipEdit_v1/authenticate/login

description The requested resource is not available.
```

Comment: So you've posted the code that works, but not the code that doesn't work, or the error you get?

Comment: ok i added it , the sarcasm was not helpful either

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using Spring Security? It looks like from your examples you are storing the password in plain text. You really shouldn't be doing this on your own if you want to have a secure app.

Comment: ok james, this was just a mock up really . I'm new to the whole grails so thanks for the advice I'll take a look .

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself. just made my form post to the authentication controller instead then redirect back to log in if it fails.